# How to import all e-mail addresses from vCard contacts into Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, vcard

When I import my vCard contacts that I exported from Roundcube into Thunderbird on my ubuntu machine, it only imports one e-mail address, even though the vCards contain multiple ones like this:

```
...
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET;TYPE=HOME:asdf@example.com
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET;TYPE=WORK:dfgh@example.com
...
```

As far as I know, this is a legal format for vCards and it worked for me in the past (with different applications that is) as well, which confuses me.

I would be happy, if someone can clear this up for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [pending](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1251456) bug for this. Better if you ask there.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Seems like they aren't eager to fix it.. :-/

Comment: Ping them. It's not impolite to bump older bugs that -if weird enough- devs just hope will fix by itself with time.